# Addition or Subtraction of Polynomials

Tags: time-complexity

Can addition (or subtraction)  of polynomials of degree $< n$ be done in constant time ?

I am quite new to algorithms. I thought about using sorted arrays for storing the coefficients. But the addition of two sorted arrays appears to be $\in O(n)$. However, I am not convinced that this is the best solution. Could someone please help clarify?

Comment: This depends on your computation model, and possibly on the representation of the polynomials (for example, whether they are sparse or not). However, in general $\Theta(n)$ arithmetic operations are required.

Comment: That's what I thought as well. I am assuming RAM model of computation btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the set $\{1,x,\ldots,x^{n-1}\}$ is a base for polynomials with degree $<n$, by definition of base, no element in this set can can be expressed as a combination of others, i.e. no element can be “ignored”.

Therefore, we know that our algorithm needs to at least read all the coefficients corresponding to $n$ elements of the base, thus making at least $n$ steps.

On the other hand, you found that adding/subtracting polynomials can be simulated by element-wise adding/subtracting lists of their coefficients, which is $O(n)$, meaning it requires less than $c \cdot n$ steps for some constant $c$.

Now we know that your algorithm needs to make some number of steps that is between $n$ and $c\cdot n$, and as @Yuval pointed, this is $\Theta(n)$ time complexity.

*(this is all for general case and I don’t know if there exists some special space of polynomials that can be represented more compactly, thus making it possible to add/subtract them faster, but also I think that you are in fact interested in a general case)*

Answer (score 0):

Storing the coefficients of the polynomial terms as arrays is the right way to go, but you will need to traverse both arrays (in one pass) to add the coefficients, and hence your running time will be $O(n)$.

The only way I can see this being faster is in one very limited case.

If you're working with polynomials of max degree 63 with coefficients from $\mathbb{F}_2$, i.e. either 0 or 1. Then you can store each polynomial as an `unsigned long` where $a_0 a_1 a_2 \ldots a_{62}a_{63}$ represents the polynomial:

$$a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + \ldots + a_{62}x^{62} + a_{63}x^{63}$$

and you have two such polynomials, say `unsigned long p1` and `unsigned long p2`, then their sum is simply `p1 XOR p2`.

In that case, addition (which is the same as subtraction) can be done in constant time. Furthermore, multiplication can be done in $O(n)$ instead of $O(n^2)$ by iterating over one polynomial and shifting the other.

This may be generalizable to any polynomials over the integers mod $n$ but I don't immediately see how.